# Why is the date format in Backoffice on local env different from the date format on dev env?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, zk, backoffice

The date format on local env is not the same as on DEV env.

=== English locale ===

"Jan 23, 2035 3:00:00 AM" - LOCAL

"Jan 23, 35, 3:00:00 AM" - DEV

=== Chinese locale ===

"2035. 1. 23 오전 3:00:00" - LOCAL

"35. 1. 23. 오전 3:00:00" - DEV

Why on DEV it looks different and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can locale settings in hac with groovy. May be locale settings different. Date/time format can be change by locale. You can check locale setting with below groovy script in hac with Console > Script Languages.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String pattern       = ((SimpleDateFormat)formatter).toPattern();
String localPattern  = ((SimpleDateFormat)formatter).toLocalizedPattern();
print Locale.getDefault();
print "\n";
print pattern;
print "\n";
print localPattern;
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a locale problem. For example, if I change the language to Chinese, here is how it will be displayed:
LOCAL: "2035. 1. 23 오전 3:00:00"
    DEV: "35. 1. 23. 오전 3:00:00"

Comment: A lot of backoffice elements not use browser locale, it can be fallback to jvm or os locale. On the other hand may be locale configuration different. Check jvm locale settings and date formats.

Comment: Here is what i found: `drools.dateformat: dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: I don't understand why it shows only 2 digits of the year on each locale (read example at the top)

Comment: I added groovy script in answer, please check two system results. Also you need to check date time format.

Comment: On Local and Dev environments returns: M/d/yy